# modifying a js file on my server and reloading it?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load, save

If I loaded a js file in a `<textarea>` with a save button below it, can I save that to an existing js file on my server and then reload it. Basically, what I want to do would work just like a wysiwyg except I want to be able to save the js to an existing file.

I am loading the js file using document.write ("`<script src='file.js'></script>`") which works.

BTW, this site would not let me put the '<' in the document write.

Comment: To include tags and other code in your post, quote them with the ` character. (I've edited your post to do so.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, but from your post I don't think you'd find it easy.

In some more depth, you'll need to use a server-side language such as PHP for this.

I won't go into how to get set up with PHP, we'll assume you know that, and if you don't then you have a great excuse to go Googling :) However, here's a simple working example script for you.

WARNING: There are a lot of pitfalls with allowing people to write to files on your server. You CERTAINLY don't want to make something like this accessible to anyone except HIGHLY trusted people. I can't over-emphasise how careful you should be with something like this unless you understand the implications of it.

```
<?php

// Change this to the file you want to be editing
// This path is relative to this script
// So if this script is in /somewhere/something/scripts/save.php
// And your file is at /somewhere/something/files/hello.txt
// This should read: $fname = "../files/hello.txt";
$fname = "something.txt";
// Now don't touch anything else :)



// This checks if we've submitted the file
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // Get the posted content
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    // Open the file, or exit with an error message if we can't
    if (!$handle = fopen($fname, 'w')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }
    // Write the new content into the file
    fwrite($fhandle, $content);
    fclose($fhandle);
}

// Get the contents of the file
$content = file_get_contents($fname);

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Editing <?php echo $fname; ?></p>
    <textarea name="content"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: You made me realize that I didn't mention PHP is okay with me. I didn't know I could do this in PHP. As far as the security hole, when they click save it only saves to js files. Could the users possibly figure this out and save to other file types? Is that what you mean? JS is client side so I am curious on what could actually happen. I am the only one who is going to have access to this btw.

Comment: Well, for a start if I can inject JS I can go session-stealing on your site. I can include remote scripts. If you parse JS files as PHP with your Htaccess (many people do) then I can embed PHP in there as well. Giving someone write access to ANYTHING on your site is dangerous, as it can almost certainly be misused. If you give them the option of which file they want to edit, they can potentially create new files on your server, overwrite your index file, and all sorts.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Well, that is good to know. Luckily, the only thing I need to modify is values (after equal signs). So, I should be ok if I nixed the text area and loaded editable divs instead. This way I can change certain values and not let the users(me) add any custom code. Can someone possibly put dangerous code after an equals sign and have it execute?

Comment: How about `12; nastyFunction();`? When you start doing that, it's all about putting VERY strict limits on what kind of data you accept. If you're editing a height or something numeric, do `$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string);` or just `$string = (int) $string;`. Things like "px" can be added by the script. If you want to allow strings, make sure you use preg_replace to cut out characters that really shouldn't be in there, and then make sure everything else gets escaped.

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea if I spelled hmmm correctly (who cares). So, you said if I was changing a height or something, "px" could come into play which could allow dangerous strings to be included. What if I only accepted numbers? If it is not a number then it doesn't get accepted. The only thing that needs to be changed is numbers. Is there any danger there?

Comment: No. Generally, if you can restrict it to letters and numbers only, it's pretty decent. As I suggested for numeric things though, you can just cast them to int with `$string = (int) $string;` and unless you've really written some bad code, the worst they can try and do is a buffer overflow, which is a *really* long shot :P Security is a whole other can of worms, but if you can apply `(int)` to some of your input, and `$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $string);` to the rest, you're not wide open.

Comment: Well, I do thank you! I missed the cast of (int) that you said. I really only need to change numeric values, so I will build a procedure that checks for this before saving. I have not tried your code from your answer, but as soon as I do I will mark this question as answered. May not happen until next week though. Thanks again. It's hard to program in 4gl progress at work and then come home and program in php and js. Very confusing.

Comment: The trick is to get a job doing PHP and JS :P There are plenty of simple examples like mine with more explanation on Google, look for something like "php read and write file" :)

Comment: Yeah, but google has become so overloaded with many different pages in its results that finding answers is not the same as it was back in 2000 when I first started using google.